# Linear Algebra 2: True or False question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{C})$. Suppose that $A^{\star}A=AA^{\star}$. Is the following true or not:

If $(1,0,1)^{T}$ and $(1,1,0)^{T}$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalues $\alpha,\beta$, then does it imply $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: If a matrix is normal, then eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are … (fill in the blank).

Comment: ...perpendicular.

Comment: Yes, orthogonal with respect to the standard inner product.

Comment: But the both are not perpendicular.

Comment: So, can they be eigenvectors relative to different eigenvalues?

Comment: No! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose, we know that the condition $A^*A=AA^*$ (normality) is equivalent to the fact that
$$
A=U^* D U
$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is unitary, that is $U^*=U^{-1}$. If $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors relative to different eigenvalues, then they must be orthogonal, because such are the eigenspaces of a matrix with this property.

Here orthogonality is considered with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since $(1,0,1)^T$ and $(1,0,1)^T$ are not orthogonal, they can't be relative to distinct eigenvalues and so $\alpha=\beta$.